# jQuery get lasted clicked on element...?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey, hope someone can help with this..

**How can I get the previous ID of a clicked div element using jQuery?**

Is this even possible?

e.g. I have two div's named *div1* and *div2*, I click on *div1* then on *div2*, how can I get the ID of div1?

Many thanks

Comment: Do you have any code written already?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Store it in a variable.

```
var lastClicked = null;

$("div").click(function() {
    if (lastClicked) {
        // use lastClicked here
    }

    // Do current click stuff

    lastClicked = this;
});
```

Comment: +1 I'd just suggest putting it into an anonymous closure too - just for neatness and to ensure `lastClicked` isn't accidentally changed elsewhere.